# ActionbarSherlock setNavigationMode on Gingerbread

Tags: android, navigation, actionbarsherlock

I have an app which has multiple fragments, **Fragment1** and **Fragment2**, and user can switch between them using a `ViewPagerAdapter`. The app also uses `ActionBarSherlock`.
Fragment1 uses `NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD` mode and Fragment2 uses `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`.

On Gingerbread and below, switching between these two fragments and rotating the phone a few times causes the actionbar to hold the list view from `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` and draw new navigation mode on top of that. So if I switch between these two fragments a couple of times and rotate the phone a few times as well, at some point I end up having a list view and a title on top of each other in my action bar!

I could solve this problem by doing a small modification at `com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$setNavigationMode`. I basically requested to hide the list view, in addition to removing it's layout from the parent. This solved the problem.

I was wondering if other people also have seen this problem, and if yes, whether they had a better solution/explanation for it?

Comment: "Fragment1 uses NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD mode and Fragment2 uses NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST" -- IMHO, switching between pages in a `ViewPager` should not be changing the primary navigation mode of the activity.

Comment: Well, maybe, though I haven't seen this yet as a design practice!